# South custom models location

Tags: django, django-south

I have quite a big django project which has a lot of applications and a lot of models.
In order to avoid circular imports several models modules must be used:

```
app/models.py
app/models_add.py
app/models_aux.py
```

and so on.
Each time I have to make a migration I have to write

```
from app.models_add import Model
```

in the app/models.py in order for South to track the model's changes.
This seems to be quite annoying because there are a lot of changes in models.

The question is: is there a way to point South which modules/files to track?

Comment: Why not to try to restructure project in the way no circular imports are presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the app_label on the Meta class of your model.

```
class Meta:
    app_label = "app"
```

Also try setting your directory structure to:

```
app/models/__init__.py
app/models/add.py
```

That should tell everything to initialize properly. This is what I recently did, but for backwards compatibility in other areas of my project I import everything in `models/__init__.py`

Comment: I guess I have to take your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've `models/__init__.py`, but south seems to ignore all the models defined in `models/*.py`. Any hints?